# In C++ how to get an EXPECT_CALL() for a function called by static function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am new to gmock and occasionally I have to write gmock unit tests.

I have function named join_server() in class say ClassServer and there is a corresponding MOCK class for ClassServer. Also I have a static function named create_service(ClassServer &RefToClassServer) defined inside another class say ClassService. The static function create_service() calls join_server() using reference to ClassServer.

I am trying to write a gmock test to assert that join_server() gets called whenever create_service() is called. But I get below error.

Expected: to be called once
Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active

My gmock test is some thing like this

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_create_service)
{   
        EXPECT_CALL(referenceToClassService, join_server());
        create_service(referenceToClassService);
}
```

Is it that checking for a function called via static function is unsupported in gmock? Any idea how do I assert that join_server() gets called whenever create_service() is executed?

In join_server() I am printing message and I confirmed that join_server() is called whenever create_service() is called.

I can provide whole code but first I want to check if it's supported or not.

Note: join_server() is also called by a member function of another class (say DummyClass). This member function is not static and in this case my check for EXPECT_CALL(referenceToDummyClass,  join_server()) succeeds as expected.

I do not understand why it fails when called by static function.
Thank you

Comment: @aschepler - Please help if you have any suggestions here.

Comment: Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`EXPECT_CALL` needs a mock object for the first argument
As you know unit tests usually have below structure

- Test Code -use-> SUT -use-> DOC

and if it comes to your code it can be

- Test Code -use-> `refereceToClassService` -use-> `referenceToClassServer`

you should set expectations on DOC(`referenceToClassServer`) and pass it to SUT(`referenceToClassService`)

If then finally `referenceToClassService` will use mocked `referenceToClassServer`

I can see you're setting expectations on `referenceToClassService` so it should be changed to `referenceToClassServer` because `refereceToClassService` is not a mock object

- before : `EXPECT_CALL(referenceToClassService, join_server());`
- after : `EXPECT_CALL(referenceToClassServer, join_server());`

※ it would be better if there is enough code to understand your situation well